# PHP to get data from API

Tags: php, json, api

The website http://tracker.ets2map.com/v2/fullmap contains the data I wish to retrieve every 10 seconds using the following code:

```
<?php

    $content = file_get_contents("http://tracker.ets2map.com/v2/fullmap");
    $result = json_decode($content);
    print_r($result);
```

I wish to get the info in the form

```
[{"name":"\u0420\u041e\u0421\u0421\u0418\u042f","x":-11409,"y":11749,"id":73469},{"name":"NikJZX","x":-12305,"y":-6239,"id":401390},{"name":"Efremov777","x":-12390,"y":-5636,"id":1755318}, ...]
```

But using the code above the data is all scrambled

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

I realise now that scramble is very misleading.
I have fixes my original problem, but now the data returns with a / in it.

Eg.
"{\"Trucks\": {\"1743637\": {\"name\": \"benanayan2\", \"h\": 0.55, \"p_id\": \"2043\", \"server\": 2, \"mp_id\": 1743637, \"t\": 1511366599, \"online\": true, \"y\": -27679, \"x\": 7203}, \"1229525\": {\"name\": \"BoeinGTranSErtu\u011frul15\", \"h\": 2.81, \"p_id\": \"868\", \"server\": 2, \"mp_id\": 1229525, \"t\": 1511366599, \"online\": true, \"y\": -9884, \"x\": -8956}, \"1717847\": {\"name\": \"[VNS] PH\u1ea0M \u0110I\u1ec6P\", \"h\": 2.2, \"p_id\": \"176\", \"server

Comment: It's not "scrambled". It simply returns a lot of data in json format. Just go through it and pick what you want. You can't really change the output of a third party API from your side.

Comment: Scrambled can mean a lot of different things. Can you provide an example?

Comment: `file_get_contents("http://tracker.ets2map.com/v2/fullmap");` missed an 'f' just mentioning it :)

Comment: @pr1nc3 Error from Jerodev edit

Comment: what do you mean by scrambled ? what exactly you want ?

Comment: Posted an answer. Try my code it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

    $content = file_get_contents("http://tracker.ets2map.com/v2/fullmap");
    $result = json_decode($content,true);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
```

I think you mean that your `print_r` messes the data in printing. Try my code to get the data print clear and readable. And also when you decode to array , use `true` , otherwise you end up with an `std class object` not easily parsed.